# The Fitting subgroup of a Frobenius group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, frobenius-groups

The Fitting subgroup of a Frobenius group is its kernel.
Any hints, suggested books or papers for the proof?

Comment: fitting?${}{}{}$

Comment: The fitting subgroup which is the subgroup generated by all normal ,nilpotent subgroups of a given group

Comment: Shouldn't that be the Fitting subgroup?

Comment: It seems unhelpful to vote to close a question as "unclear what you are asking" just because you are not familiar with the definitions of some of the terminology used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the deep result of John Thompson that the kernel of a finite Frobenius group is nilpotent. Equivalently, a finite group that admits a fixed-point-free automorphism of prime order is nilpotent.

The original reference is: Thompson, John G. (1960), "Normal p-complements for finite groups", Mathematische Zeitschrift, 72: 332–354.

There is also a complete proof in the book "Permutation Groups"  by D. Passman.